# How to debug "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" with Angular 4 data binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I am new to Angular and I am writing a custom Component as mentioned below. I am displaying a list of Course(object) that has 2 properties, id and name. This logic works fine. However when I am writing a logic to add new Course in the existing array of Course in custom-component.html using ngModel for binding, I am getting following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

My code is given below:

custom-component.component.html

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<ul class="courses">
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses" (click)="onSelect(course)"
  [class.selected]="course===selectedCourse">
      <span class="badge">{{course.id}}</span> {{course.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedCourse">
  <ul class="courses"><li>
  <span class="badge">{{selectedCourse.id}}</span> {{selectedCourse.name}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<span>Enter name: </span><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="course.name">
<span>Enter id:</span><input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="course.id">
<button (click)="addCourse(course)">Add Course</button>
</div>
```

custom-component.component.ts

```
import { Course } from './../Course';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoursesService } from '../courses.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-component',
  templateUrl: './custom-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-component.component.css']
})
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "Choosen Courses";
  selectedCourse: Course;
  courses: Course[];
  constructor(service: CoursesService) {
    this.courses = service.getCourse();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSelect(course: Course):void{
    this.selectedCourse=course;
  }
  addCourse(course: Course):void{
    this.courses.push(course);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomComponent } from './custom-component/custom-component.component';
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please don't ask for upvotes on Stack Overflow. We want votes to be as natural as possible here, and some people may even downvote you for asking. In my experience, _answering_ questions is a more reliable way to obtain rep points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comment

Initialize a new property

`course: Course = new Course()`.

Then in the `addCourse` you can pass nothing and use that object directly. After push, change the reference to keep it separately from the pushed object.

```
addCourse(): void {
   this.courses.push(this.course);
   this.course = new Course();
}
```

**This is another case, the upper one will work for you**

When you do this

```
<button (click)="addCourse(course)">Add Course</button>
```

and click the button, you don't have a property with name `course`, so undefined is passed to the function and added into the array. After this when `*ngFor` is going to update the views, the last added element is `undefined`. And trying to access it's properties will throw error.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. But my description is also true yes ? :)

Comment: How i can solve this problem, shouldn't angular create a new course object and then bind name and id property to it. What i am missing?

Comment: No it will not create automatically the object. I have provided a solution. You need to create `course` manually in the component. It will bind to it;s properties then

Comment: Thank you so much for help @SurenSrapyan, This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Error detail:

If you check a condition for `*ngIf="course"` then the error should go. because you are not initialize `course` object in your component. 
try this for fix the error

`<span *ngIf="course">Enter name: </span><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="course.name">`

### Proper Solution

You should initialize your object before use it in html

```
addCourses: Course = new Course();
```

and your html should be

```
<span *ngIf="course">Enter name: </span><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="addCourses.name">
<span>Enter id:</span><input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="addCourses.id">
<button (click)="addCourse(addCourses)">Add Course</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[(ngModel)]="course.name"
You should bind property to an initialized object, so try to declare it in component:

private course: Course = new Course(...);

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because of this block :

> Issue :
>
> For adding data there is no need of 2 way data binding , you should
>   use it when you need to updated something , for update you can simply
>   use form
>
> Reason of error is `[(ngModel)]="course.name"` and
>   `[(ngModel)]="course.id"` , as there no value to bind with input

```
<div>
    <span>Enter name: </span><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="course.name">
    <span>Enter id:</span><input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="course.id">
    <button (click)="addCourse(course)">Add Course</button>
</div>
```

It should look like this :

```
<form #cource='ngForm' (submit)='addCourse(cource.value)'>
    <span>Enter name: </span><input type="text" name="name" ngModel>
    <span>Enter id:</span><input type="text" name="id" ngModel>
    <button type="submit">Add Course</button>
</form>
```